# MVC 3 Ajax.ActionLink with JQuery UI Confirm Dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a @Ajax.ActionLink which calls a Delete Action. Now I want to use JQuery UI Dialog confirm instead the regular "Confirm" attribute of the Ajax link. 
I hook the event to the Ajax.ActionLink using the unobtrusive javaScript. But the action gets submitted and the  e.preventDefault(); throughs an error. Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Here is my jQuery code:

```
 $("[data-dialog-confirm]").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var theHREF = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('option', 'buttons', {
            "Delete this item": function () {
                window.location.href = theHREF;
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        });
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    });
```

---

Here is my MVC code:

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteConfirmed", new { id = item.Id },
                    new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                        OnSuccess = "refreshList"
                    },
                    new {data_dialog_confirm="true" }
                    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing this:
Change the `Ajax.ActionLink` to `Html.ActionLink` and in my JavaScript code I call `$.get(theHREF, null, function () { refreshList() });`

Here is the code:

```
   $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete this item": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $("[data-dialog-confirm]").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var theHREF = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('option', 'buttons', { "Yes":
        function () {
            $.get(theHREF, null, function () { refreshList() });
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }, "No":
      function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        });
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    });
```

Here is the MVC 3 ActionLink

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteConfirmed", "Category", new { id = item.Id }, new
                    {
                        data_dialog_confirm = "true"
                    })
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is how I have implemented the confirm functionality with jquery UI:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      resizable: false,
      height:180,
    });

    $(".deleteLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        buttons : {
        "Confirm" : function() {
            window.location.href = targetUrl;
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
        }
    });

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    });

} );
```

and in your html you can add the dialog div

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete the item?" > 
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>This item will be deleted. Are you sure?</p> 
</div>
```

your action link should look like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "UpdateDelete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "deleteLink" })
```

Comment: Hamid thanks for the reply. I am doing it all ajax based. So initially I had it as @Ajax.ActionLink and it would not fire the alert. So I changed it Html.ActionLink and then inside my dialog close fuciton of JavaScript I make a ajax call to delete the record. It is all working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You migth use the `OnBegin` property instead `OnSuccess`, this is just a simple example but it could help you, this is how I declare my `Ajax.ActionLink` link:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeletePeriod", "ConfigPeriod", 
new { area = "Budget", id = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    OnBegin = "confirmDeletion"
})
```

And this could be a really simple implementation of the `confirmDeletion` function:

```
<script>
    function confirmDeletion (e) {
        // Do something or validate inputs...
        e.preventDefault(); // This should prevent the event to fire...
    };
</script>
```

Regards.

Comment: There is no event passed into confirmDeletion for you to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$("[data-dialog-confirm]").click(function (e) {

    var theHREF = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('option', 'buttons', {
        "Delete this item": function () {
            window.location.href = theHREF;
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    });
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");

    return false
});
```

I'd also strongly urge you to consider using the HttpDelete verb with any MVC postback or Ajax method.

Comment: Phil, thanks for the reply. I tired it and also changed the httpPost to HttpDelete. Since this is a Ajax.ActionLink it should execute the javaScript event instead of 
window.location.href = theHREF;  this line actually forwards the page to the url /Category/DeleteConfirmed/345 where 345 is the id of the item to be deleted. Do you know what the javaScript is to be executed instead fo the window.locaiton.href=theHREF ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try calling a confirmation function from the `OnBegin` event of Ajax.ActionLink?  That way you can keep using the Ajax.ActionLink.  The OnBegin even is marked up as `data-ajax-begin` attribute so have jquery assign "return YourConfirmationFunction()" to this attribute and you should be fine.  Here's an [example of using OnBegin for confirmation dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604942/asp-net-mvc3-ajax-actionlink-conditional-confirmation-dialog-box) without jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was much easier to do this using a separate form, containing the post data, and a button which shows the dialog and then submits the form.

cshtml (Razor):

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Deactivate", "Admin", 
    new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "ReloadList();" }, 
    new {@id = "deactive-form-" + user.Id }))
{
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@user.Id" />
}
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Deactivate" 
    onclick="return ShowConfirmDlgThenSubmitForm('dialog-deactivate', 'deactive-form-@user.Id');" />
```

javascripts (with [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)):

```
function ShowConfirmDlgThenSubmitForm(dialogId, formId) {
        $('#' + dialogId).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 180,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Okay": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $('#' + formId).submit();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");                        
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```