# Jquery plug in - Ajax pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

I found this excellent plugin for ajax pop up for MVC called SimleModal, but am not able to get it to work. http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ is the website.

I want to use this plugin to pop up a view (in MVC) when a link is clicked on. Can any one show me the right direction here.. thank you..sample pseudo code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the built in jQuery-ui? Simply call $('#someDiv').Dialog(...) to make it work. Then you can use the jQuery theme roller site as well to customize your look - and you are dealing with 'base line' jQuery code.

To keep the same example syntax like Darrin added above for ease of comparison see below.

Configure your widget options and download them (you can choose from a whole lot of widgets - just the dialog if youd like or others
Do this at: http://jqueryui.com/download

Make sure you reference the css file, jquery, and the jquery ui. Download the jQuery ui and put the /images folder into your /content folder as well as the css file.

Ensure you are linking in the files (I chose google for the second file - you can choose your own local if you'd like)

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

calling it is as simple as:

```
<div id="result">bipbip</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //initialize the dialog
        $("#result").dialog({ width: 400, resizable: false, position: 'center', title: 'My Dialog', autoOpen: false,
         buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } } 
         });
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#modal').click(function () {
            //load the content from this.href, then turn it into a dialog.

            $('#result').load(this.href).dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

@Html.ActionLink("show modal", "Index2", null, new { id = "modal" })
```

For more details on the dialog see: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Comment: @Adam Tupiper: How can I use this on the click of a link. And does my 'view' code go into the Div (#someDiv) you have in the code.

Comment: you can use the helpers and do the method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133376/mvc-3-ajax-actionlink-with-jquery-ui-confirm-dialog  There is a basic way of doing this without the helper by simply calling for example $('#yourDiv').Load('@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller")'.Dialog(...); when you click on an item - but the choice is yours

Comment: @Adam Tuliper: I am interested in the calling the Dialog() method that you mention...Right now I have an action link       @Html.ActionLink("Access", "Access", new { id=item.AccessID } that successfully opens the access view in a different page on click of that link. How can I use your dialog statement to bring along the same effect but in as a pop up. I am still not clear about what goes in the #yourDiv space in $('#yourDiv')....Basically what I am asking is what code goes in place of my existing action link that brings in the Dialog/pop up effect. Appreciate your help and suggestions.

Comment: got ya- I'll add a sample shortly here

Comment: @Adam Tuliper: Thanks for the code, it works as expected. But help me out here... When I click the link - The pop up is displaying the contents of the Div with Id="result"... but the HTML action link statement @Html.ActionLink("show modal", "Index2", null, new { id = "modal" })  does not have anything mentioned about the Div... how is it all linked?

Comment: $('#modal').click links an onclick event to the href that is created from the actionlink. It then returns false so the link doesn't redirect you anywhere else in the browser as a link normally would.

Comment: @Adam Tuliper: What is Index2 in @Html.ActionLink("show modal", "Index2", null, new { id = "modal" }) - Action name? in what controller? Now the Div works fine..but I would like to show a MVC view in side that Div? Is that possible.

Comment: That is by default in whatver controller you currently rendered your view from. At least thats how it tries to determine if. If your page is /Product then the Index2 above will post to /Product/Index2. You of course can change that name to whatever _controller_ method you want (you can specify a controller and action if you want). Just replace Index2 with whatever name of an action method you want that then calls off to your view.

Comment: I have two links to compare:One,  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.AccessID }) that successfully opens the current view and calls Edit method in that view. The second link that I am using from you, the pop up modal -  @Html.ActionLink("popup Edit", "Edit", null, new { id = "modal" }) . I changed the method name from index2 to Edit , but this still opens the same result div..

Comment: I see the number of parameters I used in my actionlink is 3. But the one in your code has 4.

Comment: I got it to work.Thanks so much. I was not providing the correct route values parameter ..

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Modal()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#modal').click(function () {
            $.get(this.href, function (data) {
                $.modal(data, {
                    containerId: 'result'
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

@Html.ActionLink("show modal", "modal", null, new { id = "modal" })

<div id="result"></div>
```

Now when you click on the "show modal" link an AJAX request will be sent to the `Modal` action on `HomeController` and the resulting partial view will be shown inside the result div (so don't forget to provide one in `~/Views/Home/Modal.cshtml`).

Also make sure you checkout the [examples section](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) in the documentation for other available options.

Comment: I used your code above and I cannot get the pop up to work. I created a new partial view modal.cshtml with some test text. What is the role of 'result' in the javacript and the div? I did not understand that.

Comment: @ZVenue, the result div is where the modal will show up. Basically it will harbor the partial HTML returned by the AJAX call. And talking about an AJAX call, did you see it happening in FireBug? Do you have jquery included as well? Did you make sure that the urls to those script files are correct?

Comment: I am doing something wrong here. I have all the urls correct. I have a modal action in the home controller, I have a modal partial view. I have your code in place. I have this actionlink in a 'Books' view. When I hover mouse over the action link (pop up), it shows me books/modal but thats not how the modal view is structured. Modal view is in Home folder. I am confused. When I click on the action link nothing happens...it actually messed up my HTML that was displaying fine until this change (but that might be a different issue)

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: In the above code, how is the ActionLink triggering the Jquery code to activate the modal?

Comment: @ZVenue, I am subscribing for the click event of the link and when triggered I fetch the modal partial using AJAX and show it on the result div.