# ASP.NET MVC3 Ajax.ActionLink - Conditional confirmation dialog box

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an @Ajax.ActionLink which for which I would like display a confirmation dialog box only if certain conditions are met (user has unsaved changes).  I created a javascript function that shows the confirmation dialog as needed, and returns true or false based on the response. I tied it into the onclick event of the ActionLink but a false result does not cancel the action. Here's a sample of my code:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Done", .. , .. , 
                  new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "MyContainerId"},
                  new { onclick = "ConfirmDone()" })
```

Here's the javascript function

```
function ConfirmDone() {
    //for testing purposes we can always show the dialog box
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to lose unsaved changes?");
}
```

What's the best approach to display a conditional confirmation dialog box for the Ajax.ActionLink?

Comment: I would use a separate form and button as described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30759201/869290

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the OnBegin event:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Done", "ActionName", 
    new AjaxOptions 
    { 
        OnBegin = "return ConfirmDone()", 
        UpdateTargetId = "MyContainerId" 
    })
```

You could also use the Confirm ajax option if all you need to do is pop up a confirm box. If you need to do more custom logic (or want to use a custom dialog) then you would need to use OnBegin.

Here is an example of using Confirm:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Done", "ActionName", 
    new AjaxOptions 
    { 
        Confirm= "Are you sure you want to do this?", 
        UpdateTargetId = "MyContainerId" 
    })
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried OnBegin before, but I was missing that return keyword